# Software Testing Selenium IDE/Web driver

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

My application is using Mathml editor and i want to record button from this editor. i am using Selenium IDE, But not able to record any action from this editor.

i am new for selenium please help me out.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("editML"); 
WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.className("#editML")); 
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;     
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Heading</h1>Hello World'", editor);
```

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame("editML");
    WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.className("#editML"));
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Heading</h1>Hello World'", editor);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much in your code. Try this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("editML");
WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")); 
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;     
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Hello World'", editor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven’t tried it but it seems that in HTML 5 to have direct support for MathML elements the script could be: `driver.switchTo().frame("editML"); 
WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.className("#editML")); 
JavascriptExecutorjsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<mi><h1>Heading</h1>Hello World</mi>'", editor);`

For more info on  tags follow the below link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_mathml.htm